# How do I make the sub items selectable particular under Accordion in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm making custom Accordion with custom sub items as radio buttons. As you can see, I already create the accordion but stuck in selection of the sub item.

The issue is the when I select one item then all sub-items under that main accordion tab are selects. I want the particular one should be selected when select and the default the first one should be selected when anyone comes to this page like as first accordion tab is expanded and first sub-item should be selected.

Please help me. Below is the full code expo link mentioned:

https://snack.expo.dev/@john.ocean/crabby-churros

Screen shot of the issue is below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

checkout the updated code here : https://snack.expo.dev/T1q7WFzPP

Had some issues with the logic of your subcategory item selection. And thanks for providing expo link.

Comment: Thank you for this but need some more help. As you clear my issue but I lost the selection of sub-category which was only one from all main categories. In sort, selected sub-item should be only one from all categories sub-items. Can you help with this?

Comment: so you want to hold the selection of previous and not toggle ?

Comment: I want to make just 1 selection out of all sub-categories.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's clear now. Thank you again.